# How to run a function when setting a 'defcustom' option?

Tags: customize, customization, defcustom

Is it possible to run code when setting an option defined by `defcustom`?

For example, I would like `(setq my-package-option t)` to install a hook.

While `defcustom` has a `:set` keyword, it's documented only to run in the user interface.

---

This is close to working, it has an error about a recursive function call.

```el
(defcustom my-boolean-example nil
  "Docs."
  :set
  #'(lambda (var value)
      (if (set-default var value)
        (turn-thing-on)
        (turn-thing-off)))
  :initialize 'custom-initialize-changed
  :type 'boolean)
```

Comment: Perhaps you would rather use [?] `:initialize`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Definitions.html

Comment: Initialize only seems to run once, not after changing.

Comment: Running code when the user wrote `(setq pkg-var <foo>)` is considered a bad idea.  If the user wants to allow pkg's author to do that, they should use `customize-set-variable` insterad of `setq`.

Comment: BTW, if your variable is boolean, then the canonical way to do what you want is to use a minor mode (and tell the user to call the minor mode function instead of `setq`ing the variable).

Comment: This is meant to be an option for an existing mode, so I'd rather not have a new mode, although I suppose it could be an additional minor mode.

Comment: Despite its use of the name "mode" which you seem to interpret as meaning "something big and very visible", a minor mode is just a boolean variable with a standard "protocol" to set it such that code is run whenever you set it.  IOW, just what you want.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment to @Drew's answer you've said:

> Doesn't this require the user to use `customize-set-variable` instead of `setq` or `setq-default` ?

Indicating that you want your function to be called even when a variable is set by the likes of `setq`, which means you're looking for the variable-watcher functionality.

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Watching Variables` for details.

Note that this feature has been available only since Emacs 26.1.  Prior to that you cannot do what you're asking for.

Comment: Are you sure this is needed? `:initialize 'custom-initialize-changed` and `:set` seemed to get me some ways toward running code when setting a value.

Comment: Well do you, or do you not, want the function to run when `setq` is used to set a variable?  You indicated that you did.  If you don't, then the comment I quoted is confusing.

Comment: I do, although I thought this is what `custom-initialize-changed` supported, I must have misunderstood.

Comment: `custom-initialize-changed` is a value for `:initialize` which "should be a function used to initialize the variable when the ‘defcustom’ is evaluated" -- it has no bearing on any *other* assignment to that variable's value.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that `:set` is used only for interactive use of Customize.

Functions `customize-set-variable` and `customize-save-variable` respect the `:set` function of the `defcustom`.

> **`customize-set-variable`** is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp
>   function in `cus-edit.el`.
>
> `(customize-set-variable VARIABLE VALUE &optional COMMENT)`
>
> Set the default for `VARIABLE` to `VALUE`, and return `VALUE`.
>
> `VALUE` is a Lisp object.
>
> **If `VARIABLE` has a `custom-set` property, that is used for setting
>   `VARIABLE`, otherwise `set-default` is used.**
>
> If `VARIABLE` has a `variable-interactive` property, that is used as if
>   it were the arg to `interactive` (which see) to interactively read the value.
>
> If `VARIABLE` has a `custom-type` property, it must be a widget and the
>   `:prompt-value` property of that widget will be used for reading the value.
>
> If given a prefix (or a `COMMENT` argument), also prompt for a comment.

Comment: Doesn't this require the user to use `customize-set-variable` instead of `setq` or `setq-default` ?

Comment: Added example to question.

Comment: Yes, it requires you to use one of the functions I mentioned. You indicated that you wanted to take advantage of `defcustom`'s `:set` function. Your question has now morphed into a different question. Clearly `setq` cannot take advantage of `defcustom`'s `:set` function. Had you made clear your intention I would have mentioned what @phils mentioned: variable watchers.